# Can early Initialization be faulty in some android cases?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have BookFragment:

```
public class BooksFragment extends Fragment {
private final String ALL_PUBLISHERS = "Wszystkie Wydawnictwa";
```

and later on in private void method I'm accessing ALL_PUBLISHERS field like this:

```
if(chosenPublisher != null && chosenPublisher.equals(ALL_PUBLISHERS))
    doStuff();
```

Now there seems be nothing wrong wit the code and I've personally never run into trouble with this but thanks to Google Play Developer Console I've notice that some users run into NullPointerException when accessing ALL_PUBLISHERS field.

Now:

- trouble is in ALL_PUBLISHERS field - [stack](http://morse.swirski.name/pastes/ldjf78njp73l55v1i2nu47vrz9c26aw)
- my BookFragment is used in FragmentStatePagerAdapter,
- bug happens in various android devices

What me be cause of this sensation?

Answer (score 2):

I think you are interpreting the stacktrace in the wrong way; the log states the following hint

> Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean
>   java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference

The method is invoked on the left-side variable which is `chosenPublisher`. If your are modifying the `chosenPublisher` variable in some concurrent way in your code, an NPE exception could occur in some interleaving because your *if* statament is not atomic.
On the other hand, your static field `ALL_PUBLISHERS` is initialized at class loading: if your are not modifying it, it cannot be null.

In conclusion, my suggestion is to use the `ALL_PUBLISHERS` variable as your left-side element in your conditional statement:

```
if(chosenPublisher != null && ALL_PUBLISHERS.equals(chosenPublisher))
    doStuff();
```

Comment: While at it just `ALL_PUBLISHERS.equals(chosenPublisher)` would be enough. And make ALL_PUBLISHERS static.